I train yolo model with my own data set but there is no test result
I am training the model using the Yolov3 model with the data set I received from Kaggle. Model training is completed and I add the new weights to the backup folder. I run one of the fruits I trained with for testing, but object detection does not occur. The same image appears as Prediction.jpg. The training seems to be decent, but I don't understand why it can't detect objects. Please help me.
Train Terminal Code:
./darknet detector train /Users/melisabagcivan/darknet/data/obj.data /Users/melisabagcivan/darknet/cfg/yolov3.cfg /Users/melisabagcivan/Desktop/Projects/Bitirmeprojesi/yolov3.weights

Test Terminal Code:
./darknet detector test /Users/melisabagcivan/darknet/data/obj.data /Users/melisabagcivan/darknet/cfg/yolov3.cfg /Users/melisabagcivan/darknet/backup/yolov3_final.weights -thresh 0.25 -out predictions.jpg

I set up and edited obj.data and obj.names and yolov3.cfg files.
I have 3 classes: apple, banana and orange. I have properly set the values ​​such as filter and class values ​​in the cfg file according to the 3 classes.
cfg file 
[net]
# Testing
batch=64
subdivisions=1
# Training
subdivisions=16
width= 608
height=608
channels=3
momentum=0.9
decay=0.0005
angle=0
saturation = 1.5
exposure = 1.5
hue=0.3

learning_rate=0.001
burn_in=1000
max_batches = 6000 # classnum * 2000
policy=steps
steps=3600,4800 # max_batches num %80, %90 
scales=.1,.1

In addition to the .jpg images in the data set, there are .txt files with the same name in yolo format.
File image:

The train.txt and test.txt files containing the paths to all the images are also ready.
When I run the test command in the terminal, it works, but the picture looks the same, there are no bounding boxes that detect objects. I'm sure I have Opencv installed. I am using macOS. Why is it not detecting it? Someone please help. I cleaned the darknet many times by saying make clean and ran it by saying make opencv = 1, but the result does not change.
[yolo] params: iou loss: mse (2), iou_norm: 0.75, obj_norm: 1.00, cls_norm: 1.00, delta_norm: 1.00, scale_x_y: 1.00
Total BFLOPS 137.613 
avg_outputs = 1052318 
Loading weights from /Users/melisabagcivan/darknet/backup/yolov3_final.weights...
 seen 64, trained: 32013 K-images (500 Kilo-batches_64) 
Done! Loaded 107 layers from weights-file 
Enter Image Path: /Users/melisabagcivan/Desktop/Projects/yoloOD/dataset/test/38_Orange.jpg
 Detection layer: 82 - type = 28 
 Detection layer: 94 - type = 28 
 Detection layer: 106 - type = 28 
/Users/melisabagcivan/Desktop/Projects/yoloOD/dataset/test/38_Orange.jpg: Predicted in 6738.129000 milli-seconds.

I tried it with many images and it doesn't draw the box in any of them. I don't understand whether it can't detect it or whether I'm making a mistake while testing it.

Several things to note:

I suspect you are using the old abandoned repo, just based on the paths you give in the example commands.  Note the AlexeyAB repo was abandoned in July 2021.  https://www.ccoderun.ca/programming/yolo_faq/#which_repos_to_use_and_avoid

The new Darknet/YOLO repo people should be using is the one sponsored by Hank.ai.  All new development is being done there.  See here:  https://github.com/hank-ai/darknet#table-of-contents

Looks like your training images contains cropped images of fruit, is that right?  That first image of an apple that takes up almost 100% of the image...if you train with that, you're telling Darknet/YOLO that the objects you want to detect must take up ~100% of the image.  So if you then pass in images that have apples, it will fail to detect anything.  See here for details:  https://www.ccoderun.ca/programming/yolo_faq/#crop_training_images

Your training command is not the recommended one.  Please see the Darknet/YOLO FAQ where this is explained:  https://www.ccoderun.ca/programming/yolo_faq/#training_command

You should also post a copy of your chart.png file.  Maybe have a peek at your other chart_*.png files as well to see if all 3 classes are training the same way.  But at the very least, please edit this question and add your chart.png file before trying to figure out why something cannot be detected.

I strongly recommend you download and run DarkMark to test your annotations prior to training.  I cannot begin to count the number of issues this has solved over the years.  It was written specifically to find and prevent problems.  (Disclaimer:  I'm the author.)  https://www.ccoderun.ca/programming/yolo_faq/#what_software_is_used

Join the Darknet/YOLO discord server.  Lots of folks there to help people get started.  https://discord.gg/zSq8rtW


